# cheetah template importing functions

Tags: python, templates, cheetah

So I am having some trouble trying to import functions and run them inside my cheetah templates.

So I have one file that lives at /docroot/tmpl/base.html
and then another file that is /docroot/tmpl/comments.html

inside of comments I have something that looks like this

```
#def generateComments($commentObj):
 code for generating comments
#end def
```

then inside of base.html I want to have a syntax like this

```
#import docroot.tmpl.comments as comments
<div class="commentlist">
 $comments.generateComments($commentObj)
</div>
```

However when I run that output I just get the contents of comments.html printed out including the #def generateComments in raw txt.'

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Cheetah compiles templates to Python classes. When you import `comments` module the module consists of a single class also named `comments`. You need to explicitly instantiate the class and call its `generateComments` method. So your code should be

```
#from docroot.tmpl import comments
<div class="commentlist">
 $comments.comments().generateComments($commentObj)
</div>
```

The first `comments` is a module, `comments.comments` is a template class in the module, `comments.comments()` is an instance of the class, `comments.comments().generateComments($commentObj)` is a call to its method. To simplify the code a bit import the class:

```
#from docroot.tmpl.comments import comments
<div class="commentlist">
 $comments().generateComments($commentObj)
</div>
```